# Docker: dial tcp 216.58.199.241:443: i/o timeout

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, docker-image

I was learning Docker with Go when I suddenly faced an issue. I started out with a simple REST API using Gin (just a single endpoint). Here are the Dockerfile contents

```
FROM golang:1.18.3-alpine3.16

RUN mkdir /app


COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o main main.go

CMD ["./main"]
```

When I try to build this image, I face this issue

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.34kB
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.18.3-alpine3.16
 ---> 155ead2e66ca
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebf8b860e476
Step 3/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94df62bc2cc3
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ddf613b6357c
Step 5/7 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Running in 884573e1e568
go: github.com/gin-contrib/sse@v0.1.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/gin-contrib/sse/@v/v0.1.0.mod": dial tcp 216.58.199.241:443: i/o timeout
The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Something goes wrong when running Step 5 (RUN go mod download) I guess.
It would be really great if you could help me out with this. Thanks!